# extract table from multiple pages in a website

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping

I want to extract tables from the following link https://www.imei.info/carriers/ and save it to csv
following is my code :

```
for i in range(1,44):

url = 'https://www.imei.info/carriers/?page='+str(i)
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]
df.to_csv('imei.csv')
```

When reading it in csv, it shows data from only last page

Answer (score 1):

this is because you are erasing the previous page each time you write `to_csv`. What you can do is retrieve all the DataFrames, `concat` the list of DataFrames and then write the output to csv:

```
dfs = []
for i in range(1,44):
    url = 'https://www.imei.info/carriers/?page='+str(i)
    html = requests.get(url).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    dfs.append(df_list[-1])
output = pd.concat(dfs)
output.to_csv("imei.csv")
```